# Check checkboxes nullPointerException

Tags: android, checkbox, menu

I'm confused as to how to check checkboxes that are in the activities' menu file, not its layout file. First I had the code below but with `findViewById(R.id.uniformScale);` rather than `findViewById(R.menu.dressing_room).findViewById(R.id.uniformScale);` but that threw a nullPointerException so I added the `findViewById(R.menu.dressing_room)` but that causes the same error. I know I have to reference the checkbox in the menu file because it's not in the layout file but I'm not sure how. Or I add it to the layout file, but i'm not sure how to do that either. Note: they might be radioButtons because checkableBehavior="single" but I've tried changing type to RadioButton and get the same exceptions thrown. Thanks.

Within the menu file for the activity:

```
<item
                        android:title="Sticker Settings"
                        android:id="@+id/action_cancel1"
                        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings">
                        <menu>
                    <group android:checkableBehavior="single"
                        >
                        <item android:id="@+id/uniformScale"
                            android:title="Change Size"
                            android:checked="true" />
                        <item android:id="@+id/rotation"
                            android:title="Rotate"
                            android:checked="false" />
                    </group>
                    </menu>
                    </item>
```

Within the activity:

```
    @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mainActivity, menu);
            checkCheckboxes();
            return true;
        }

    private void checkCheckboxes(){

            CheckBox checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.menu.dressing_room).findViewById(R.id.uniformScale);
            if (checkBox1.isChecked()) {
                photoSorter.setRotate(1);
                photoSorter.setAnisotropic(2);
            }
            else{
                checkBox1.setChecked(true);
                photoSorter.setRotate(2);
                photoSorter.setAnisotropic(1);
            }
        }
```

**EDIT** Trying blackbelts answer:

```
    private void checkCheckboxes(Menu menu){

            MenuItem checkBox1 = (MenuItem) menu.getItem(R.id.uniformScale);
            if (checkBox1.isChecked()) {
                photoSorter.setRotate(1);
                photoSorter.setAnisotropic(2);
            }
            else{
                //checkBox1.setChecked(true);
                photoSorter.setRotate(2);
                photoSorter.setAnisotropic(1);
            }
        }

@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mainActivity, menu);
        checkCheckboxes(menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
private void checkCheckboxes()
```

to

```
private void checkCheckboxes(Menu menu)
```

and use `menu.findItem(R.id.uniformScale)` to retrieve the element

Comment: Thanks. How would I get the menu? I tried this `@Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  int itemId = item.getItemId();
  Menu menu = (Menu) findViewById(R.menu.dressing_room);
  checkCheckboxes(menu);
  switch (itemId) {...` and `private void checkCheckboxes(Menu menu){
  
  RadioButton checkBox1 = (RadioButton) menu.getItem(R.id.uniformScale);
  if (checkBox1.isChecked()) {
   photoSorter.setRotate(1);
   photoSorter.setAnisotropic(2);
  }
  else{
   //checkBox1.setChecked(true);
   photoSorter.setRotate(2);
   photoSorter.setAnisotropic(1);
  }
 }` same error

Comment: you are calling checkCheckboxes inside onCreateOptionsMenu. onCreateOptionsMenu has a Menu as parameter

Comment: Thanks. Moved it there. Got this exception: 01-31 21:44:15.434: E/AndroidRuntime(14702): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException. Atleast its a different exception :P

Comment: where do you get this exception. Edit your question and add relevant snippet of code. Do not post code in comment, please

Comment: Thanks it is updated now. I changed type to MenuItem, but I get the same error when it is RadioButton and MenuItem.

Comment: ok, one small thing, please. Edit your question and post the code you are using right now. Otherwise is impossible to understand what's going on

Comment: That is the code I'm using right now. Where it said trying your answer. Have not changed it.

Comment: try with findItem not with getItem: menu.findItem(R.id.uniformScale)